# The use of JPA/JDO in Android and in Google App Engine

Tags: java, android

I've recently been reading up on implementing the Google App Engine with my android app. As I am relatively new to java, I discovered JPA and JDO. I have since been reading up mostly on JPA. The more I read on it though, the more confused I get.

I have two quick questions:

1. Is there an advantage of using JPA over custom setter/getter classes? I have been using custom getter/setter classes to persist data for the lifetime of my activity. I am confused about this part because creating an entity class for JPA looks almost exactly the same as my custom getter/setter classes minus the annotations. All I am doing is using these custom classes to populate custom listview rows.
2. Is there an advantage of using JPA other than writing data to a database? This is strictly for android. If all I want is to create simple entities with very few relationships in my Google Datastore, would I need all the features of JPA? I am planning to write a custom class for myself to put entities in the Datastore. These entities would be as simple as a user with his name, password and email, with 2 or 3 parents/ancestor. I just want to know if I can continue with this or if I will have to spend a lot of time reading about JPA and JDO.

Comment: A benefit of using JPA is that the entities can be auto generated by tools such as Eclipse.

Comment: Main benefit of JPA is that you are use OOP paradigm, not relational.